# Piers Anthony character "Subtle"

Tags: story-identification, novel, piers-anthony

In the late 1960s, I recall reading a Piers Anthony novel with character "Subtle". "Subtle" was a special agent with his mind adjusted so his memory could be downloaded and given to his fellow agents.

"Subtle" was agent "Sub" with the "humanizing suffix" of "tle".  Which novel was this?

Comment: Late 60s, you say? Anthony had published very little by then. Are you sure it was he?

Comment: This is definitely *Omnivore*, then.

Answer (score 7):

### This is [*Omnivore*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1606593803)

First published in 1968, this is one of Piers Anthony's earliest works. It tells the story of three people sent to a planet of fungal life-forms. A notable element is the presence of individuals with three very different diets: omnivore (the standard human state as of 2016), herbivore (i.e. vegetarian), and carnivore (basically a vampire).

The agent's name is *Subble*, not Subtle:

> Subble dropped noiselessly to the floor. 'Technically, I'm not a man,
>   in that sense. I'm a number. I'm identified by a three-letter code,
>   SUB, **with a humanizing suffix.** I differ from SUA or SUC or SUD no more
>   than my code does.'

His mind certainly has been seriously altered:

> ' An agent's memory is washed blank before every assignment. I have been
>   given three addresses and a caution signal. That was, literally, all I
>   knew about you before I landed. Your name, where to find you, and a
>   warning of danger.'

And his memories can be shared with other agents:

> 'But some memories might help you do the next job better.'
>
> 'Such memories are erased from the individuals, then implanted
>   uniformly in the entire corps.'

Comment: IIRC, it's the first of a trilogy, the other two being *Orn* and *OX*... Err, maybe that's *0X*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - True